# Start program with user rights from within a elevated program

Tags: winapi, elevation

I have an application that requires elevated rights (it is something like a custom installer).
From within this application, I use ShellExecute() to show a PDF file.
It seems as if the Adobe Reader is started with the same rights as the calling application. I would like the Adobe Reader however to be started with standard user rights and not elevated.

Is there some way I can do that? (It would be in Delphi, but for this problem the language probably doesn't matter).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6419772/203458 - while it's not an answer to that question (despite being accepted) it is the answer to yours

Answer (score 0):

There's no really straightforward way to do this unfortunately.

One way you can do it is with Task Scheduler - you use the `ITaskService` interface to schedule a task to run immediately, using the non-elevated credentials of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve cannot be done very easily and is not supported. However, it is possible using a modicum of hacking. Aaron Margosis wrote an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app.aspx) describing one technique.

To quote the pertinent section, you will need to carry out these steps:

> 1. Enable the SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege in your current token
> 2. Get an HWND representing the desktop shell (GetShellWindow)
> 3. Get the Process ID (PID) of the process associated with that window (GetWindowThreadProcessId)
> 4. Open that process (OpenProcess)
> 5. Get the access token from that process (OpenProcessToken)
> 6. Make a primary token with that token (DuplicateTokenEx)
> 7. Start the new process with that primary token (CreateProcessWithTokenW)

The article contains a download link for some demo C++ source from which it should be simple enough to translate to Delphi.

Comment: There is a simplier way - `CreateRestrictedToken()` and `CreateProcessAsUser()`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379316.aspx for more details.

Comment: @Remy Not sure that is simpler. You have to hard code which privs to remove.

Comment: only if you want to, or you can specify the `DISABLE_MAX_PRIVILEGE` flag to disable most privileges.

Comment: In any case, it looks like `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` is the way to go: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2013/06/18/launching-a-process-as-a-normal-user-from-an-elevated-user.aspx

Comment: [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643)