# Create own URL Protocol with QT4

Tags: windows, qt, registry, protocols

I have already found out, how I create my own protocol for windows ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)).

Now I have tried to create such an entry with my QT application, but I have some problems:

1. I'm not able to write in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. I think, I need administrator privileges, but how do I achieve that? I don't want, that my app is always running in Admin-mode.
2. I don't know, how to write the "(Standard)"-Entries. If I create this entries manually and export them as a reg-file this "(Standard)"-Entries look like

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myprotocol]
@="URL:SomeDescription"
```

Is there any possibility to create these entries with Qt's QSettings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the QSettings try [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qsettings.html#accessing-the-windows-registry-directly).

For the admin rights, NO, admin rights are needed **to create** the registry entries.

Comment: thanks for the settings link... I haven't read the docs till the end :) blame on me. Actually, I'm able to create "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" entries, but "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" is admin-only. Is it a good idea to create a *.reg-file and then execute it with "regedit.exe"?

Comment: as a workaround I have created another executable and run this, if there was no registry found. According to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6418873/1360842) I was also able to run the executable as admin, so the registry entries can be written correctly.