# i am trying to make my .exe application run as administrator on any users computer

Tags: windows, rights

I have made an .exe windows Application which needs to run with Administration rights. When i open my app it does not prompt me the user account control in which one has to put his password.

 so my app does not work.

my windows users don't know that it will only work by right clicking and choosing run as administrator.
i need want that when clicked it should prompt the user to enter their password.

i am little frustrated because i have searched google whole day but found nothing.
i am not using Visual Studio

Comment: I have tried CMDs runas command but it does not prompt but asks the password in cmds window

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6418873/268093) answer help?

Comment: No,if i start a game which i have saved in program files directory .windows first prompts me to enter your password first

Comment: I am not using VS2008

Comment: See the checkmarked answer at http://superuser.com/questions/604927/how-do-i-configure-my-application-to-run-as-administrator-automatically.

Comment: http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-make-an-application-run-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is right click your .exe file then choose compatibility tab and check the option “Run this program as an administrator” in Privilege Level section.