# Opening command line program with elevated rights

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, dll-injection

I am currently writing a DLL injection program (C++) which adds specified certificate to `certmgr.exe`.

I wrote the whole thing connected with injection (`OpenProcess`, etc.). When I am executing it - attached to `svchost` - my DLL is not loading since it seems that it doesn't have such rights as `svchost` has.

How can I pass rights?

In my DLL file, I am using `system("certmgr.exe -add ....")` and I think this might be the problem because the command line opens as a separate program (as if I opened it via `start`).

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6418873/2747962)

Comment: I don't know if I described my problem correctly:
I have a code that injects to svchost and when I try r\to run f.ex. a simple messagebox, there is no problem with it. The problem occyrs when I try to make my code execute sth with administrator rights.
I want my dll to work exactly the same as if I opened command line as administrator and passed the command:
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\certmgr.exe" -add -all -c "c:\Users\Damian\Desktop\wwwtesthttpdev.crt" -s -r localMachine root.

Comment: I think the link perfectly caters to your problem, what do you think it doesn’t answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ShellExecute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) using the "runas" argument, which will make it try to run as administrator

```cpp
ShellExecuteA( NULL, 
    "runas",  
    "c:\\windows\\certmgr.exe",  
    "-add ....",     
    NULL,                 
    SW_SHOWNORMAL  
);
```