# Add privileges to a process

Tags: c++, security, process

I have an application with system account. This app launches another process. I want to let the created process to write to a file in a specific directory (which needs system account rights). How can I achieve it.
Here is the code that launches my process. I **don't** need to run the second process with system account.

```
CString ProcessFullPath = "myProcessPath";
while(NbTrysLaunchingIAPM<=NbMAXTrysLaunchingIAPM && resLaunch==0)
{                       
    resLaunch=CreateProcess(ProcessFullPath.GetBuffer(),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &si,
    &pi);
    if(resLaunch==0)
    {
        NbTrysLaunchingIAPM++;  
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't admin privileges inherited from the calling process?

Comment: I'm sorry, I confused system account with administrator privileges.  I've edited my question

Comment: I'm confused.  It's sounding to me like you're saying that the child process both does and doesn't need system account rights.

Comment: it needs only to write in a file which is located in a directory that needs high prvileges. I'm obliged to run it with user account and write to that directory. I hope It's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Basic (low-level) approach would be like this:

- chdir to the directory the new process will write to
- fork, clone, whatever
- drop user privileges ([assuming you're using windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1533017/823738))
- execute the process

Hope that helps.